# Datetime seconds are not accurate

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to print the current time before my normal prints

```
global begtime
begtime = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
global secondtime
secondtime = begtime.split(' ')[1]
global time
time = '[' + secondtime + ']' + ':'
print time
```

`datetime.datetime.now` returns in the format of :

```
year.month.date hour.minute.second
```

so I first split at the '.' to get the individual times, then I split at the space to get just the time.

then I formatted it as [hour:min:sec]

It works, but the time is not correct, it will print same time for all prints even if they happen minutes apart.

I want the exact time for every print.

Comment: it's bad practice to use globals

Answer (score 0):

For your code, you're probably setting the time earlier in your program and then accessing it later thinking it is generating a new time. It won't generate a new time every time you print it. It will only generate a new time every time you run `begtime = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]`

The better way to do this would be to use [`Date.strftime(format)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). I've included an example of this below.

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime('[%I:%M:%S]'))

time.sleep(10)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime('[%I:%M:%S]'))
```

This will print the current time and then 10 seconds after the current time after 10 seconds.